# RXJava flow equivalent for Login + Webservicecall

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java

i'm digging into rxJAva and i'm not sure i'm using the right logic.

What 'd need to achieve is the following. Consider (for now

```
 LoginResult l;
 if (hasCachedLoginResult()) {
   l = getCachedLoginResult();
   if ( l.timePassed > 20mins) {
      l = null;
   }
 } 
 if (l == null) { // no cache or cache expired.
   if (canPerformLogin() /* user has entered credentials */ ) {
     l = performLogin();
   } else {
     showMessageToUserAskingCredentials();
     return;
   }
 }

 if (! l.isLoggedIn() ) { 
   showErrorToUser(l.errorMessage());
 } else {
   proceedWithNextWebserviceCall();
 }
```

This is because i'd like to always pre-execute this "routine" on every webservice call that requires the user authentication.

I've already written the "performLogin" and "proceedWithNextWebserviceCall" as Observables but i don't know how to chain them together.

I saw there is a 'cache' operator but proceedWithNextWebserviceCall might throw an error when the user is not authenticated ( User have changed password and we're using the cached loginresult with the old cookies ) so i'd also need to invalidate the cached loginResult and wasn't able to find any documentation on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am also digging into RxJava, but your code doesn't seems rx at all for me. For chaining action, map method is really useful. So using rx and lambda, i would write it like this.

```
    Observable.from(hasCachedLoginResult())
            .map(hasCache -> hasCache ? getCachedLoginResult() : null)
            .map(loginResult -> loginResult != null ? loginResult : performLogin())
            .subscribe(loginResult -> proceedWithNextWebserviceCall(loginResult), errorLogin -> showError(errorLogin));
```

In short, you can use map method to chain action together.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't cover the cache. I was also loooking to see  if there was a way to leverage the .cache operator of rxjava